# Placing divs horizontally so that they partially overlap

Tags: html, css

I would like to have a table of elements (pictures) arranged horizontally, and such that the elements partially overlap, in order to save some space.

I attempted to solve it through CSS. Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div.tableel
            {
                height : 100px;
                width : 100px;
        display: table-cell;
                position: relative;
            }
      div.tableel ~ div.tableel 
      {
        left: -30px;
        font-size: 24pt;
      }
      div.row
      {
        display: table-row;
      }
      div.table
      {
        display: table;
      }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="table">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="tableel" style="background-color: red;">
          reg
                </div>
                <div class="tableel" style="background-color: blue;">
          ge
                </div>
                <div class="tableel" style="background-color: yellow;">
          rg
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I do not understand is why the font is set correctly, but the third element is not shifted to the left, as I would expect to.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer if we've helped you solve the issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I do not understand is why the font is set correctly, but the
>   third element is not shifted to the left

It is being shifted exactly as you intended it to.

The reason **you** are not able to see it is because when the second `div` shifts to left, it creates a gap between itself and the third, which is being filled up by the third.

This fiddle will help you see this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/byayxob0/

If you want to stick to doing it this way, then you will have to get the last `div` to move left by double the amount:

```
div.tableel:last-child { left: -60px !important; }
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/byayxob0/1/

But, this will be a problem for you if you have indeterminate number of `div`s. You will have to change the `left` property cumulatively, which CSS cannot do for you.

---

That said, a simpler way to do what you want, would be to just keep the `div`s inline and then use negative margins to control the overlap.

**Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/4gaotuwL/**

**Demo Snippet:**

```css
div.tableel {
    height: 100px; width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div.tableel:nth-child(1) { background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); }
div.tableel:nth-child(2) { background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5); }
div.tableel:nth-child(3) { background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5); }
div.tableel:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="tableel">reg</div>
        <div class="tableel">ge</div>
        <div class="tableel">rg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Great answer. Actually the number of elements changes dynamically, so I guess CSS alone won't do it.

Comment: @gramuc: The inline negative margins would be easiest for you as it will not only keep the markup and css simple, but will also handle dynamic number of elements. See the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the second element is moved 30px to the left so that it would be 30px further away from the 3rd element, then when you shift the 3rd element 30px to the left it just closes the gap you made. If you want to move the 3rd element to overlap the second by 30px, you'd need to move it 60px to catch up to it and overlap it.

Comment: with position:relative I would have expected that it shifts to the left with respect to the position that it otherwise would have.

Comment: `position:relative` moves elements from where they would be placed in the DOM if no positioning had been applied. So if you move them `30px` to the left they move from where they would have been side by side before any other movement happens.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.table {
  width: 300px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
}
.tableel {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.default .tableel ~ .tableel {
  left: -30px;
}
/* I just moved the second block*/

.scene-1 .tableel:nth-child(2) {
  left: -30px;
}
.scene-2 .tableel:nth-child(2) {
  left: -30px;
}
/* I also moved the third block - but 60pixels. (as 30pixel will move it beside 2nd block*/

.scene-2 .tableel:nth-child(3) {
  left: -60px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Your code</h2>
<div class="table default">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);">
      reg
    </div>
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.7);">
      ge
    </div>
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.7);">
      rg
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Scene 1</h2>
<div class="table scene-1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);">
      reg
    </div>
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.7);">
      ge
    </div>
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.7);">
      rg
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<h2>Scene 2</h2>
<div class="table scene-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);">
      reg
    </div>
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.7);">
      ge
    </div>
    <div class="tableel" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.7);">
      rg
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do `left: -60px;` to the third element in order to go -30px left because the second element is -30px left.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**
If you are having an unknown number of divs and wanted to make this work regardless of how many divs you have without having to specify incrementing left values then I suggest using a negative margin.

Simply change this:

```
            div.tableel {
            height : 100px;
            width : 100px;
            display: table-cell;
            position: relative;
        }
```

To This:

```
            div.tableel {
            height : 100px;
            width : 100px;
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
        }
```

and then give the blocks a negative margin by replacing this:

```
     div.tableel ~ div.tableel 
  {
    left: -30px;
    font-size: 24pt;
  }
```

to this:

```
            div.tableel {
            font-size: 24pt;
            opacity: 0.5;
            margin-left: -30px;
        }
```

So looking at the code and various answers; I think you're getting confused on the

```
      div.tableel ~ div.tableel 
  {
      position: relative;
    left: -30px; /* <------------------This */
    font-size: 24pt;
  }
```

left: -30px portion.

Looking at your 3 boxes. You have Box number 1, 2 and 3. Based on your selector; You are moving box 2 to the left -30px and moving box number 3 to the left by -30px.

When you move the first box to the left by -30px; you are creating a gap between box 2 and box 3 of 30px:

[image]

This means that Box 3 needs -30px to close the gap. and an additional -30px to overlap so box 3 needs to be -60px for this to work:

-30px:

[image]

-60px:

[image]

So in short.. I would replace this portion of your code:

```
     div.tableel ~ div.tableel 
  {
    left: -30px;
    font-size: 24pt;
  }
```

with this simplified fix:

```
   div.tableel{   
    font-size: 24pt;
  }
  div.tableel:nth-child(2){
    left: -30px;
  }
  div.tableel:nth-child(3){
    left: -60px;
  }
```

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8uhnwhwt/